# Missing Claims via JWT Web Token

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following code that creates a JWT token in a webapi core application.

```
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.Username!=null?userInfo.Username:string.Empty),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userInfo.Email!=null?userInfo.Email:string.Empty),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, userInfo.AccountId!=null?userInfo.AccountId.ToString():Guid.Empty.ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, userInfo.UserId!=null?userInfo.UserId.ToString():Guid.Empty.ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInfo.ClientId!=null?userInfo.ClientId.ToString():Guid.Empty.ToString())
                };

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                  _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                  claims,
                  null,
                  expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                  signingCredentials: credentials);

                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

However when I try to get the claims back after the client has called a webapi end point, I only have the following claims. As you can see the "JTI" claim is fine, but the "UniqueName" claim is missing.

```
[0]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: }
    [1]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: }
    [2]: {jti: f7c5af77-d0c4-4026-9b33-2fe9fbf5ee28}
    [3]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    [4]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: b34a1b42-df24-42a3-93d7-68e88523602f}
    [5]: {exp: 1581973428}
    [6]: {iss: Test.com}
    [7]: {aud: Test.com}
```

What do I need to do to get the claim to appear?

Just to note that the claim that I set as JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName does appear in the claims but not under that name. Its value is set under the item

```
[4]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: b34a1b42-df24-42a3-93d7-68e88523602f}
```

However this is not brought back when use the following as it is null

```
identity.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName).Value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However this is not brought back when use the following as it is null
>
> `identity.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName).Value;`

To fix the above issue, you can try to clear the inbound claim type map using following code snippet in Startup.cs

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

**Test Result**

Set testing value for `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName`

```
//just for testing purpose

new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, "b34a1b42-df24-42a3-93d7-68e88523602f")
```

Can get expected value using `identity.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName).Value`

[image]

Comment: Lots of appreciation! I just do that on a validator instance `tokenValidator.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`